# Error Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000 Fail to get file list

Tags: java, android-studio

I am doing an exercise with tabLayout, a frame has some textlayout and another one has buttons with a scroll. When I try it, it gives me a series of errors that I can't find, I leave you the code and the logcat

```
 2020-01-07 20:20:13.336 27052-27052/? I/om.example.ej1: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2020-01-07 20:20:13.348 27052-27052/? E/om.example.ej1: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-01-07 20:20:13.561 27052-27052/com.example.ej10 I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
2020-01-07 20:20:13.578 27052-27114/com.example.ej10 E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.ej10
2020-01-07 20:20:13.579 27052-27114/com.example.ej10 E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2020-01-07 20:20:13.579 27052-27114/com.example.ej10 E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.ej10
2020-01-07 20:20:13.579 27052-27114/com.example.ej10 E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2020-01-07 20:20:13.691 27052-27052/com.example.ej10 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-01-07 20:20:13.694 27052-27052/com.example.ej10 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ej10, PID: 27052
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ej10/com.example.ej10.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3276)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2022)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:359)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7418)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.ej10.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3251)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2022) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:359) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7418) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935) 
2020-01-07 20:20:13.706 27052-27052/com.example.ej10 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27052 SIG: 9
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ej10">
     <application>
           android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

main

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FrameLayout fm1;
    private TabLayout tabLayout1;
    private PrimerFragment pF = new PrimerFragment();
    private SegundoFragment sF= new SegundoFragment();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fm1 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fm1);
        tabLayout1 = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout1);
        reemplazarFrameLayout(pF);
        tabLayout1.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                Fragment fragment = null;
                switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        fragment = pF;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        fragment = sF;
                        break;
                }
                reemplazarFrameLayout(fragment);
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
        });
    }
        private void reemplazarFrameLayout(Fragment fragment) {
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fm1, fragment);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
```

I really don't understand the error, I searched the internet but I can't find anything. I don't have any Array so the array error doesn't make sense